# neverending python import failure problems

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, python-poetry, python-3.10

I am using python 3.10, poetry package manager, and running vs code based on a windows subsustem for linux (ubuntu 22.04)

I was able to produce a fix yesterday and though my imports issues now would be over, but come today it still fails, not having done anything to the directory hierarchy or nothing. Just added a file Y in a folder, and another file X in another folder. Both folders where there yesterday, and had the
`__init__.py` file.

My project structure looks like this.

```
RepoName
|-src
|  |-project
|       |- packageA
|       |     |-module1.py -\> myclass1
|       |     |- __init__.py
|       |- packageB
|       |     |-module2.py -\> myclass2
|       |     |- __init__.py
|       |-scripts
|       |     |-myfile1.py # this is where i try to import the class from module1
|       |     |-myfile2.py # this is where i try to import the class from module2
|
pyproject.toml
poetry.lock
```

========

yesterday spend all day troubleshooting why i could not import a module from packageA.
I figured out that when setting up poetry it already assumes a certain "standard"(to my suprise I thought it would enforce when using the "poetry new" command as this sets up a basic hierarchy).
The implementation of the src folder solved this issue yesterday and I was able to import class 1 using

```
from src.project.packageA.module1 import myclass1
```

and try out the code i created.

Today however, I turn on my computer, create the module2.py file, implement som code and do a

```
from src.project.packageB.module2 import myclass2
```

And it fails.

This is getting extremely frustrating. I have spend much time on imports in the past as well, and just when I think I have got the hang of it, it throws me another curveball.
I know that the python interpreter first seaches for the directory, then dirs in the pythonpath and lastly a dependant list of directores. Yesterdays fix should still work, and I dont know why it doesn't.

How can I gain more visibility into what is happening when importing? And how can I in a consistent way move my projects forward in a consistant manner without spending loads of time with imports.
This is really draining me, and I cant produce anything with this stuff hanging over me all the time.
Would appreceate if someone can help me out here.

I have tried changeing the directory hierarchy (fixed the problem yesterday)
I have tried adding the PYTHONPATH to my .zshrc script.
I have tried countless ways of getting poetry to understand and load the hierarchy that I have on screen in my IDE, including spcifying paths in the .toml file.
I have tried using sys, but really want to try and avoid this as it should not be nessecary if the interpreter just interpret the hierarchy that i have on screen.

Comment: Please show the content of your `pyproject.toml` as well.